# Scrapy downloading json-files from site?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

i tried to create a scrapy spider to download some json-files from a site -

This is my scrapy spider:
(first tested the spider - so it only outputs the link to the json-file which works fine - see commented code below)
But i want to download the json-files to a folder on my pc.

```
import scrapy

class spiderWords(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'spiderWords'
  allowed_domains = ['kaikki.org']
  start_urls = ['https://kaikki.org/dictionary/Spanish/words.html']

  def parse(self, response):    
    tmpLinks = response.xpath("(//ul)[2]/li/a/@href").getall()
    for l in tmpLinks:
      l = response.urljoin(l)    
      request = scrapy.Request(l,
                              callback=self.parseDetails)     
      yield request

  def parseDetails(self, response):
    tmpLinks2 = response.xpath("(//ul)[2]/li/a/@href").getall()        
    for l2 in tmpLinks2:
      l2 = response.urljoin(l2)    
      request = scrapy.Request(l2,
                              callback=self.parseDownload)     
      yield request

  def parseDownload(self, response):
    class DownfilesItem(scrapy.Item):
      file_urls = scrapy.Field()
      files = scrapy.Field  

    tmpDownloadLink = response.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'JSON')]/a/@href").get()
    tmpDownloadLink = response.urljoin(tmpDownloadLink)
    item = DownfilesItem()     
    item['file_urls'] = tmpDownloadLink
    yield item         
    # yield {
    #   "link": tmpDownloadLink,
    # }
```

And this are the changes which i did in the settings.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
  'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1,
}
IMAGES_STORE = r'C:\DOWNLOAD\DATASETS\Spanish'
```

But unfortunately the download of the json-files is not working.

How can i download the json-files to the defined folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. `item['file_urls']` should be a list.
2. `IMAGES_STORE` should be `FILES_STORE`

```py
import scrapy


class spiderWords(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spiderWords'
    allowed_domains = ['kaikki.org']
    start_urls = ['https://kaikki.org/dictionary/Spanish/words.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        tmpLinks = response.xpath("(//ul)[2]/li/a/@href").getall()
        for l in tmpLinks:
            l = response.urljoin(l)
            request = scrapy.Request(l,
                                     callback=self.parseDetails)
            yield request

    def parseDetails(self, response):
        tmpLinks2 = response.xpath("(//ul)[2]/li/a/@href").getall()
        for l2 in tmpLinks2:
            l2 = response.urljoin(l2)
            request = scrapy.Request(l2,
                                     callback=self.parseDownload)
            yield request

    def parseDownload(self, response):
        class DownfilesItem(scrapy.Item):
            file_urls = scrapy.Field()
            files = scrapy.Field()

        tmpDownloadLink = response.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'JSON')]/a/@href").get()
        tmpDownloadLink = response.urljoin(tmpDownloadLink)
        item = DownfilesItem()
        item['file_urls'] = [tmpDownloadLink]
        yield item
        # yield {
        #   "link": tmpDownloadLink,
        # }
```

**EDIT:**

In order to set the file's name do this:

settings.py:

```py
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'yourprojectname.pipelines.ProcessPipeline': 1,
}
FILES_STORE = r'C:\DOWNLOAD\DATASETS\Spanish'
```

pipelines.py:

```py
import os
from urllib.parse import unquote
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline


class ProcessPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        file_name = os.path.basename(unquote(request.url))
        return file_name
```

**EDIT 2:**

writing additional information to file:

```py
import json
import scrapy


class spiderWords(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spiderWords'
    allowed_domains = ['kaikki.org']
    start_urls = ['https://kaikki.org/dictionary/Spanish/words.html']
    erg = {}

    def parse(self, response):
        tmpLinks = response.xpath("(//ul)[2]/li/a/@href").getall()
        for l in tmpLinks:
            l = response.urljoin(l)
            request = scrapy.Request(l, callback=self.parseDetails)
            yield request

    def parseDetails(self, response):
        tmpLinks2 = response.xpath("(//ul)[2]/li/a/@href").getall()
        for l2 in tmpLinks2:
            l2 = response.urljoin(l2)
            request = scrapy.Request(l2, callback=self.parseDownload)
            yield request

    def parseDownload(self, response):
        class DownfilesItem(scrapy.Item):
            file_urls = scrapy.Field()
            files = scrapy.Field()

        key = response.xpath('//ul[@class="breadcrumb"]/li[last()]/text()').get()
        self.erg[key] = response.url

        tmpDownloadLink = response.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'JSON')]/a/@href").get()
        tmpDownloadLink = response.urljoin(tmpDownloadLink)
        item = DownfilesItem()
        item['file_urls'] = [tmpDownloadLink]
        yield item

    def close(self, reason):
        with open('erg.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(self.erg, indent=4))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - works great now!
Maybe one additional question - is there some way to change the name of the saved file?
(it now has some generated key like 5a032ff2.json - but i would like to have, probably additional at the beginning - the name of the link in tmpDownloadLink)
Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks you again - this works also great!
Maybe one last question - is it also somehow possible to yield additonal some output to a json-file (so eg. yield the files to the disc as we did it now - but additonal create a erg.json with for example the link or some other data?

Comment: @Rapid1898 There's more then one way to do it. See `edit 2` for an example.